# Seeking particle-like solutions to sets of nonlinear PDE's

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I am looking for references that can (or an expert who is willing to) suggest methods for finding stationary, axisymmetric solutions to a set of nonlinear field equations related to, but not quite the same as the Einstein-Maxwell equations.  It's easy enough to write down the time-independent form of the equations, but I'm not sure where to go from there. The equations are:

$$ \partial_\mu \partial_\mu A^\nu= j^\nu, $$
where

$$ j^\nu=K(F_{\alpha\beta} F^{\beta\nu}  -1/4 (F_{\mu\beta}  F^{\mu\beta}) \delta^{\alpha\nu} )\epsilon_\alpha, $$

$$ F_{\alpha\beta} = \partial_\mu A_\alpha -\partial_\alpha A_\beta, $$

and $\epsilon_\alpha$ is the timelike unit eigenvector of $F_{\mu\beta}.$

The constant K is an adjustable parameter.  The field variables are complex vectors $A_\alpha$, and the products are as shown, not products of complex conjugates.  "Stationary solution" in this context means any $A_\alpha (x_\gamma) $ that is a solution to the equations and is either independent of  $x_o$ or is periodic in $x_o$.  The solutions also need to be stable.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable in this fields, but would be helpful if you could present your set of "nonlinear field equations". If these equations belong in work ou are yet to publish, then you may have a sound reason for hiding them, but I'm not sure this website is the best place to look for research colleagues.

Comment: I haven't been able to get LaTex to work, so the equations look really clumsy when I write them down.  I'll wrestle with LaTex some more and try to put the equations in a readable form, then add them to the question.